# $Ker(T) \subseteq V$ Is A Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $V,W$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$, and $T$ a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$

$Ker(T) \subseteq V $ to prove that $Ker(T)$ is a subspace can we say that:
by definition $0\in Ker(T)$ and because V is a vector space, and in any vector space there are two trivial subspace (0,V) therefore $Ker(T)$  is a subspace?

Comment: You have to prove that $\ker(T)$. Satisfies the axioms for subspaces: if $x$ and $y\in\ker(T)$, show that $x+y\in\ker(T)$, and that if $x\in\ker(T)$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar, then $\lambda x\in\ker(T)$.

Comment: I tried to find a "shorter" way, but I know realize that my claim is wrong due to the definition of $Ker(T)$, as it can contain numerous elements and not just 0.

Comment: $0$ is not in $Ker(T)$ by definition. $0$ is in Ker $T$ for every liner map, this *follows* from the definition of *linear map*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning isn't correct. Try the following hints:

To start with, one can show that for any linear map $T$, $T(0) = 0$ and so $0 \in \text{ker }T$ (you should prove this). Thus, since $\text{ker }T$ is non-empty, it suffices to show that it's closed under linear combinations. So suppose $u,v \in \text{ker }T$ and $\lambda, \mu \in F$, and show that $T(\lambda u + \mu v) = 0$ using the fact that $T$ is a linear map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show, that

- $\mathbf{0}_V\in\ker(T)$
- $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in\ker(T)$ implies $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\in\ker(T)$
- $a\mathbf{u}\in\ker(T)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{F}$

You've already said that $\mathbf{0}_V\in\ker(T)$. Now, let $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in\ker(T)$. Using the linearity of $T$, we get
\begin{align*}
T(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})=T(\mathbf{u})+T(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{0}_W,
\end{align*}
so $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}\in\ker(T)$. In a similar way, we obtain
\begin{align*}
T(a\mathbf{u})=aT(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{0}_W.
\end{align*}

Comment: What does this add to my answer?

Comment: @Ale You posted your answer while I was writing this, so I hadn't seen it. Agreed, yours is a better hint.

Comment: I don't care of reputation. I'm deleting my answer =)